# MySql - Grouping by a column of specific value only (without UNION)

Tags: mysql

Given the following data;

```
column a | column b | column c
________   ________   _______
   A     | apple    |   1
   P     | pear     |   3
   O     | orange   |   4
   A     | apple    |   1
   P     | peach    |   2
   P     | pear     |   3
   P     | peach    |   1
   A     | apple    |   4
```

I would like to select and only group (and sum) by apple. The rest of the columns would not be grouped and so the following would be the output;

```
column a | column b | column c
________   ________   _______
   A     | apple    |   6
   P     | pear     |   3
   O     | orange   |   4
   P     | peach    |   2
   P     | pear     |   3
   P     | peach    |   1
```

Is the above possible **without** using a UNION?

Comment: Do you have any column with value `a` where column b isn't equal to apple?

Comment: @PaulKaram No, in fact this column could be simply marked "n/a" if necessary if it does not apply for the purpose of the apple grouped record.

Answer (score 2):

**Without using a UNION**

```
SELECT tbl.id,tbl.a,tbl.b,tbl.c FROM (
SELECT id,a,
    CASE WHEN b='apple' THEN @ap:= (@ap+c) ELSE c END as c,
    CASE WHEN b = (SELECT b FROM fruit WHERE id > frA.id AND b='apple' LIMIT 1) THEN b ELSE CONCAT(' ',b) END as b
    FROM fruit AS frA, (SELECT @ap:=0 ) AS apc
    ) as tbl
WHERE tbl.b REGEXP '^[ ].*$'
```

LIVE DEMO : [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3838d1/1)